# Second TeXstudio dictionary for subset of documents

Tags: texstudio

I am using TeXstudio 2.11.0 on a Windows 10 machine. I would like to be able to have a "local" dictionary. By this, I mean that for a number of documents, but not all documents, I would like to have a second dictionary which is where I would add words particular to those documents (heck, even one document).

I am unable to determine if this is even possible, but from the configuration page it looks like I may be out of luck.

For example, when I am writing documents to assist students in my operating systems class, there are certain "words" that I would like to not have flagged; uid, gid; proc and the like. I would like these flagged in other documents, however.

Other than changing the dictionary configuration each time I move from one class of documents to another, is there a solution that will work for me? I would really like the option of adding new words to this second dictionary but manually adding them is fine as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by creating your own custom extended dictionary based on the language you want to use, [adding the OS specific keywords](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/developers/how-tos/editing-the-spell-checking-dictionaries), then [letting TeXstudio know about it and use a magic comment](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION03) to automatically use the extended dictionary in the respective source files.

Comment: Thank you, @alwaysask. I was away for a while but recently returned and verified that this technique works as you described. I will use this technique going forward.